# sql average items per user without being given the counts

Tags: mysql, sql

If a table has bogos in it and each bogo's columns are like: bogo_id, user_id, baga_id, and the relationship between users and bagas is many to many, how to write an sql statement that finds the median number of bagas per user?

### sample data:

- user_id | baga_id
- 1          1
- 1          1
- 1          1
- 1          1
- 2          1
- 3          1
- 1          2

### Expected output:

- baga_id    |  median per user
- 1              1
- 2              0

Comment: (Hint: [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) will be useful - just because you aren't *given* counts doesn't mean you can't *get* the counts. Now, start by attempting some queries!)

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Comment: added sample data in qusetion

Comment: Are you looking for the average or the median? Your title states average, but your question states otherwise.

Comment: I was looking specifically for median and anyway median is a type of average